# ELF - ld not combining symbols used in relocations

Tags: compiler-construction, code-generation, elf, relocation

I am trying to emit a relocation to a symbol defined in another file, so reverse engineered how GCC does it and came up with this relocation:

```
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
00000000001f  000200000002 R_X86_64_PC32     0000000000000000 _R_Print - 4
```

And this symbol (in the file with the relocation, which doens't actually define the symbol):

```
Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
  2: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _R_Print
```

However, when I link this with the file that defines the symbol, the relocation resolves to 0 (so must be following the undefined symbol) and the symbols are not combined (symbol table of the linked executable):

```
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     4: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _R_Print
     8: 00000000004000db     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _R_Print
```

What's going on here, why aren't the symbols combined (ld is linking other symbols defined in the same way but the other way round (I define them and my assembly code relocates against them) just fine?